# Android Pass Intent to Activity only if activity is already active?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver which I want to pass onto an activity but if and only if the activity is visible.  I don't want to start it up unless its already visible.  Is there an option for this?  Or a way to pass it but not have the activity become visible?  Or if you know a way for an activity be register as a broadcast receiver that would work too I suppose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can archive this by registering the Receiver in the onResume() and unregister the receiver in the onPause() method. This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Just what I needed to do.